How to prevent scroll move when multiple Bootstrap modal is opened
Modal1 is long enough to traverse the screen.
If I scroll Modal1 down and show Modal2, Modal1's scroll will unintentionally move to the top.
After that, if Modal2 is shown, the scroll of Modal1 will not move to the top.
But if I close Modal1 and show Modal2 again, the scroll of Modal1 moves to the top.
I would like to prevent Modal1 scroll from moving when Modal2 is shown.


$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#openExampleModalToggle').on('click', () => {
    $('#exampleModalToggle').modal('show');
  });
  $('#openExampleModalToggle2').on('click', () => {
    //$('#exampleModalToggle2').modal('show');
    $('#exampleModalToggle2').modal('show');
  });
});
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Modal 1</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Show a second modal and hide this one with the button below.
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Show a second modal and hide this one with the button below.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="openExampleModalToggle2">Open second modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle2" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel2" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel2">Modal 2</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Hide this modal and show the first with the button below.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="openExampleModalToggle">Open first modal</button>




I believe what you need to do is hide the 1st modal , when you open the second modal . I have made the same changes here and it looks okay to me as far as scroll is considered . Does it work for you ?


$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#openExampleModalToggle').on('click', () => {
    $('#exampleModalToggle').modal('show');
  });
  $('#openExampleModalToggle2').on('click', () => {
    //$('#exampleModalToggle2').modal('show');
   $('#exampleModalToggle').modal('hide');
    $('#exampleModalToggle2').modal('show');
  });
   //close 2nd modal and open the first one 
   $(".btn-close").on('click', () => {
      $('#exampleModalToggle').modal('show');
      $('#exampleModalToggle2').modal('hide');
  });
});
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Modal 1</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Show a second modal and hide this one with the button below.
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        Show a second modal and hide this one with the button below.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="openExampleModalToggle2">Open second modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle2" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel2" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel2">Modal 2</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Hide this modal and show the first with the button below.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="openExampleModalToggle">Open first modal</button>




@Yogi Thanks. Did not understand the ask fully . Have made the changes to reflect what you said .

I'm sorry that my explanation is not detailed.
But your answer is different from my intention.
What I want is that the position of Modal1's scroll does not change when Modal2 is seen with Modal1 remaining.

Modal1 has a very long body, so if Modal2 shown, it's annoying to go to Modal1's original scroll position.
